# Kafka stream - how to group by twice?

Tags: stream, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to create a bar graph showing how many pixel colors there are in an image; the image gets updated every 3 seconds, hence my bar graph updates too.

I have a topic which collects JSON objects which has it's key as the image creation date, and the value is the hex value (e.g #FFF).

I want to group by the key, so it's group by images, and then group by hex values for each of the group and do a .count().

How do you do that?

I was thinking streams.groupByKey()... then groupBy by hex value but I need to convert the KTable to KStream...

**UPDATE**

Sorry at my lack of explanation as I was typing it on my phone.
I'm going to try and explain again.

By the way I change some stuff. Here is my github if you want to read what I am doing: https://github.com/Lilmortal.

- My project "HexGraph-source-connector" picks up any images in a
  specified directory and push the image path to a topic.
- "HexGraph" project picks it up, and using Akka, the actors will get
  all the pixel hex codes individually and start to push the messages
  to another topic.
- "HexGraph-stream" is my kafka stream part.

But it's quite long, I doubt you will read it lol.

Anyways I read from a topic, I get messages like this {imagePath: {hexCode: #fff}}.
The image path is the key, the hexCode is the value. I can have one to many imagePaths, so my idea is that my front end will have a websocket that will pick it up. It will display an image, and there is a bar graph on top of it which have the amount of pixel color codes. e.g. there are 4 #fff, 28 #fef, etc.

Hence I want to group by the imagePath, and then I want to count each pixels for that imagePath.

For example:

- {imagePath1: {hexCode: #fff, count: 47}}
- {imagePath1: {hexCode: #fef, count: 61}}
- {imagePath2: {hexCode: #fff, count: 23}}
- {imagePath2: {hexCode: #fef, count: 55}}

So here imagePath1 have 47 #fff, and imagePath2 have 23 #fff.

That's what I am trying to do atm.

Comment: You can convert KTable to KStream with KTable#toStream(). It doesn’t cost anything. But it won’t help you here, because then you’ll have a stream of aggregates, keyed by the aggregated key, and then what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe select by a composite key before grouping? Something like this:

```
SteamsBuilder topology = new StreamsBuilder();

topology.stream("input")
   .selectKey((k, v) -> k + v.hex)
   .groupByKey()
   .count()
```

This doesn’t groupBy twice but gets you the desired effect.

---

**UPDATE** after comment:

```
class Image {
    public String imagePath;
}

class ImageAggregation {
    public String imagePath;
    public int count;
}

class ImageSerde implements Serde<Image> {
    // implement
}

class ImageAggregationSerde implements Serde<ImageAggregation> {
    // implement   
}

KTable<String, ImageAggregation> table = topology
  .stream("input", Consumed.with(new org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.LongSerde(), new ImageSerde()))
  .groupBy((k, v) -> v.imagePath)
  .aggregate(ImageAggregation::new,
             (k, v, agg) -> {
                 agg.imagePath = v.imagePath;
                 agg.count = agg.count + 1;
                 return agg;
             }, Materialized.with(new org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde(), new ImageAggregationSerde());
```

---

**UPDATE 2** after post update:

```
class ImageHex {
    public String imagePath;
    public String hex;
}

class ImageHexAggregation {
    public String imagePath;
    public Map<String, Integer> counts;
}

class ImageHexSerde implements Serde<ImageHex> {
    // implement
}

class ImageHexAggregationSerde implements Serde<ImageHexAggregation> {
    // implement   
}

KTable<String, ImageHexAggregation> table = topology
  .stream("image-hex-observations", Consumed.with(new org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.LongSerde(), new ImageSerde()))
  .groupBy((k, v) -> v.imagePath)
  .aggregate(ImageHexAggregation::new,
             (k, v, agg) -> {
                 agg.imagePath = v.imagePath;
                 Integer currentCount = agg.counts.getOrDefault(v.hex, 0)
                 agg.counts.put(v.hex, currentCount + 1));
                 return agg;
             }, Materialized.with(new org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes.StringSerde(), new ImageHexAggregationSerde());
```

Comment: Hey there, sorry for the late reply.

I'm thinking:
Have a KStream that contains messages like "{imagePath: #fff}", "{imagePath: #efe}".

And a KTable which has "{imagePath: (#fff, 13)}".
When a message {imagePath: #fff} arrives, the KTable will be updated to {imagePath: (#fff, 14)}".

Comment: You mean that’s what you want, right? The KStream becomes that KTable, and the count is incremented like that? And keys are a timestamp you want to group by?

Comment: Ah yes that solution is getting somewhere! I am playing around with it at the moment, thanks Dmitry!
But that counts how many hexCodes overall, I need to count per image.
I updated my question in detail, hope it helps. Thanks a'lot for sticking through this! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hmm I'm going nowhere with this.The only solution I can think of is ImageAggregation have a hashtable of hex code as the key and the count as the value for each of the hex code.

So I will be sending messages to my final topic as:
{imagePath: {#fff: 300, #fef: 454}}.

This is not ideal... I prefer to send one hex code one at a time.

Comment: Ohh I was confused. I just read your update. It makes it clearer. I’ll post an update. “imagePath” in your value object is an actual unique image path, right? Is that image path also the key you are using to send to Kafka (when you send to Kafka, every record you send should also have a key)?

Comment: And yeah you totally should have a hashmap on each aggregation that holds each color and its count. That is the solution. Cool project.

Comment: Yeah all the imagePaths are unique.
Ignore all the comments I made previously except for the update in my actual post. My comments and post contradict each other because I keep changing my solutions hoping to find an optimal solution lol.

In my original post, I was thinking of using unique ID as my keys, now it's imagePaths.

Comment: I updated the answer. It's basically what you expected with the map collecting all the counts on the aggregate. The model class `ImageHex` should be mapped from the deserialization of your JSON, so it might look different. Same with the aggregation—its field names etc can just match whatever you want your JSON to look like, or whatever is easiest for your deserialization/serialization.

Comment: Thanks alot man!
But it seems like this line `agg.counts.put(v.hex, agg.counts.getOrDefault(v.hex, 0) + 1));`

I have an image with 400 #fff; it's just a black square image, but agg.counts seem to be empty constantly when I put a debug on it, the result is always 1.

I will keep debugging hmm

Comment: Post your code somewhere? `KStream#peek()` is good for debug logging.

Comment: Done, I put my code on my post.

It looks like Map doesn't work well with aggregation, I'm currently googling this

Comment: Oh wait! There was a bug in my deserialization! I'm going to test this more, it might be working!

Comment: Hey! Thanks a'lot so much man! I'm not used to stack overflow, so I presumed I just upvote and click on the tick sign?

Really really appreciate your help! This thing is driving me crazy for days because I'm just not used to kafka haha.

Comment: Really glad it worked out for you. Cool project! Come here and post the URL if it makes it to the web :). Thanks for the upvote/tick

Comment: Haha will do, I'm just cleaning up and will start playing around with akka and kafka clusters before I start working on my websockets and my front end later.